# Laravel validation hook

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Is there a hook I can use in `AppServiceProvider::boot()` that will run every single time the validator is called?

I have a config value and when it is set to `true` I want all validation to throw an error regardless of what rules passed.

Comment: I suspect you could override `$this->app->validator` with a custom validator class.

Comment: Why do you need the validation?